# Jenkins failed to locate Cygwin

Tags: shell, jenkins, cygwin

I want to run shell scripts with Jenkins on windows with Cygwin but I get this error message. I have my shell program path set to: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe. And my shell command is this: npm install
./script/test
./script/deploy.

This is my github repository: https://github.com/y0u-s/test.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to locate Cygwin installation. Is Cygwin installed?
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$GetCygpathTask.getCygwinRoot(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:138)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$GetCygpathTask.call(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:142)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$GetCygpathTask.call(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:112)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$1.getCygpathExe(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:104)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$1.cygpath(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:86)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$1.launch(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:65)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.util.jna.JnaException: Win32 error: 2 - The system cannot find the file specified
    at hudson.util.jna.RegistryKey.check(RegistryKey.java:124)
    at hudson.util.jna.RegistryKey.open(RegistryKey.java:223)
    at hudson.util.jna.RegistryKey.openReadonly(RegistryKey.java:218)
    at hudson.plugins.cygpath.CygpathLauncherDecorator$GetCygpathTask.getCygwinRoot(CygpathLauncherDecorator.java:127)
    ... 18 more
```

I am kinda stuck right now, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm going to be posting this solution in a couple places as this is what worked for me and this issue appears in a couple questions. Unfortunately the solution requires some registry editing.

TLDR Solution:

```
- Open regedit.
- Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - SOFTWARE - Wow6432Node
- Right click on Wow6432Node New->Key name it Cygwin
- Right click on Cygwin New->Key name it setup
- Right click on setup New->String Value name it rootdir
- Right click on rootdir Modify set it to your cygwin folder mine was "C:\cygwin64"
```

The reasoning

https://github.com/jenkinsci/cygpath-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/cygpath/CygpathLauncherDecorator.java

Is the Jenkins code for how it finds Cygwin. Line 115 is the start of a for loop where it looks initially in the SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node, then in SOFTWARE for the Cygwin directory. In my case I already had "SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup\rootdir  Only it does not seem to be able to find it. I hazard there is some issue where it exits the loop early or does not check the SOFTWARE directory correctly. Using the solution posted above is an unpleasant work around to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell scripts without Cygwin. Just add this code to your build.xml

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = "de.myapp"
version = '2.2.0'

android {
    ...
}

uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        maven {
            name "snapshot_repo"
            url "http://192.168.178.85:8081/nexus/content/repositories/myapp_snapshots"

            credentials {
                username  "admin"
                password  "admin123"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

i hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Set in your Jenkins **Shell executable** variable with (`C:\cygwin64\bin\bash`).

Set CYGWIN variable in **System variable** (`CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning`)

Make sure that  you put (**`#!/bin/bash`**) in the beginning of the shell command

Comment: How do you do all of these things? are some of them done on the windows server? are other done within the jenkins interface? what screens?